# Assign a row from an old dataframe to a new one only if the "if" condition is verified

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, row

I'm trying to work on a dataframe on R about banks for my thesis!
In particular I have to select some rows from my dataset.

- First I check if there are 2 equal name in the column "company name"
- Second I check which is the "consolidation code" in the column
- Lastly, depending on the consolidation code, I try to assign the row of my dataset to a new dataset.

The last point is the one where I'm having problems.. I think I'm following all the instructions from how to assign a row to a dataset, but still cannot find a solution and I hope you can help me!

```
data <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(total)) {
  for (j in 2:nrow(total)){
    if(total$Company_name[i]==total$Company_name[j] & total$Consolidation_code[i] == "U2")
       {data <- total[i,]}
    else if (total$Company_name[i]==total$Company_name[j] & total$Consolidation_code[i] == "C2")
       {data <- total[i,]}
    else if (total$Company_name[i]==total$Company_name[j] & total$Consolidation_code[i] == "C1")
       {data <- total[i,]}
    else if (total$Company_name[i]==total$Company_name[j] & total$Consolidation_code[i] == "U1")
       {data <- total[i,]}
                       }
                     }
```

This is the code I wrote.. please let me know if you can spot my mistake and let me know if you know an easier way to code my problem.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** now this code works, but it only assign 1 row to the new dataset.. can you spot the problem?

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(data)`? So we can help you better by reproducing your problem.

Comment: Sounds like a join or merge with an additional condition for me. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: @Quinten the dataframe is an excel file that I dowloaded from bankfocus, do you think I can attach somehow it?

Comment: @MartinGal thank you for your answer, but I don't have to merge 2 datasets.. I have to create a new one with the rows of the old dataset that verify the if condition

Comment: Please share a reproducible example. I still believe a `join` or `merge` could be of use.

Comment: @MartinGal I found out that I just needed to add 'else if' condition since I have so many else..  problem: it seem that it only execute the for loop once.. can you imagine why?                      and as already said, the dataset I'm using I did not find it on internet, but I downloaded from bankscope.. so I don't have any idea about how to show it

Comment: You should replace `for (j in nrow(total)) ` with `for(j in 1:nrow(total))`. Else it will only be executed for one value of `j`. The same for `i`.

Comment: it only adds 1 row :( @MartinGal.. but really thanks so much for trying to help!!

Comment: You could try `data <- rbind(data, total[i,]) ` instead of `data <- total[i,]`. The latter overwrites `data` with each iteration, so only the last call will be saved.

Comment: OMG!!! you made it!!! it worked!! I only had to remove duplicates (for sure I can improve the code.. but at least now I have the dataframe on which I can work)... THANKS @MartinGal

Comment: You're welcome. Next time please try to make a great reproducible example. You're more likely to get a good and fast answer for your problem. :)